# Catch IllegalStateException with Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, objectify, ktor

I use Objectify 6.0.5, Ktor 1.2.6, com.google.appengine:appengine:1.9.60

I set up web.xml, bootstrapper by tutorial https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Setup

web.xml

```
    ...
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.group.Bootstrapper</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    ...
```

Boostrapper

```
class Bootstrapper : ServletContextListener {
    override fun contextInitialized(sce: ServletContextEvent?) {
        println("         contextInitialized")
        ObjectifyService.init(
            ObjectifyFactory()
        )

        ObjectifyService.register(User::class.java)
    }

    override fun contextDestroyed(sce: ServletContextEvent?) {}
}
```

When I call this method

```
    fun save(entity: T) {
        ofy().save().entity(entity)
    }
```

I catch error

```
2020-01-05 17:55:09 ERROR Application:104 - Unhandled: GET - /test
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call ObjectifyService.init() before using Objectify
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:511) ~[guava-28.1-android.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.factory(ObjectifyService.java:34) ~[objectify-6.0.5.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy(ObjectifyService.java:51) ~[objectify-6.0.5.jar:?]
    at com.group.dao.BaseDao.listAll(BaseDao.kt:15) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.group.ApplicationKt$module$2$2.invokeSuspend(Application.kt:50) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.group.ApplicationKt$module$2$2.invoke(Application.kt) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:268) ~[ktor-utils-jvm-1.2.6.jar:1.2.6]
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:141) ~[ktor-utils-jvm-1.2.6.jar:1.2.6]
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:161) ~[ktor-utils-jvm-1.2.6.jar:1.2.6]
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:27) ~[ktor-utils-jvm-1.2.6.jar:1.2.6]
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing.executeResult(Routing.kt:147) ~[ktor-server-core-1.2.6.jar:1.2.6]
...
```

I run datastore using 'gcloud beta emulators datastore start'. It definitely run. May be is not connect to it?

When I run app use appengineRun, datastore also is run?

Comment: Sounds like your contextInitialized() method isn't being called.

Comment: contextInitialized() is called. Check via debuger

Comment: I run datastore using 'gcloud beta emulators datastore start'
It definitely run. May be is not connect to it?

Comment: Maybe some sort of classloader issue? Look at the code for `ObjectifyService.init()`, it's one line. Somehow you're calling `ofy()` in a different static context than you called `init()`.

Comment: @stickfigure Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: I couldn't even begin to guess. But it should be very easy to hunt down, it's basic Java (or Kotlin) 101 stuff. There's one class with one static field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that `ktor` uses coroutines. Coroutines run in a thread pool by default and the `ObjectifyFilter` is only active for the thread receiving the request. I use this workaround until I find something better:

```
get(path) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Unconfined) {
        val content = page.doGet()
        call.respond(content)
    }
}
```

The `Unconfined` dispatcher runs the coroutine in the same thread who started it, at least until the first suspend.